# IE11 refuses cross site request with "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied."

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cors

So I've been trying to understand what's going on here and I can't wrap my head around it. So we have react app that accesses a resp api (cross origin). This works just fine, except for one single api call. The only difference between this call and others that do work is the query string. And since it appears that IE stops before it even attempts to access the web server (de network tab does not even show a "Method"), it can't have anything to do with the response headers from the web server (which, for an OPTIONS call are always the same for any valid url). Even so, it says:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

All other (major) non-IE browsers work just find BTW.

My suspicion is that the URL (or query string) is to long. Its almost 3000 characters long, and as far as I have seen IE's limit is 2K for the query string. If so, why not just say so?

Comment: yeah 2083 bytes is longest URL IE will work with.

Comment: Yes, but even so, then just tell me that the URL is to long in stead of giving me a totally unrelated error message.. Anyway, I can indeed confirm that this is the problem. I now put to long query stings in the body of a GET, and that seems to fix the problem. And yes, I realise that a body for a GET is not quite standard, but it seems to work universally (and it worked out of the box on the web server).

Comment: FYI I get the exact same error message when trying to do a cross origin request without using the CORS methods, but in this case the request does not even show up in the network tab.